# Find rotation matrix of one vector to another using R

Tags: r, rotation, geometry

I would like to calculate one (any) rotation matrix between two n-dimensional vectors using R.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Have you found an algorithm/formula that you can suggest here? At present this is a "give me the codez" question ...

Comment: @BenBolker I don't think it's "give me the codez" question. It's rather a question "please tell me if there is something built-in I didn't find before I start writing my own codez".

Comment: Thank you Ben, I've tried to improve my question by including what I've already done. My question was more in the direction pointed by avysk

Comment: if it's not "give me the codez", then it's "looking for a library/resource" ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598750/finding-the-rotation-matrix-in-n-dimensions includes a Matlab algorithm which allows to find one rotation matrix transforming a vector *x* to another vector *y*. The code can be transformed to R:

```
# Function returns a rotation matrix transforming x into y
rotation = function(x,y){
  u=x/sqrt(sum(x^2))

  v=y-sum(u*y)*u
  v=v/sqrt(sum(v^2))

  cost=sum(x*y)/sqrt(sum(x^2))/sqrt(sum(y^2))

  sint=sqrt(1-cost^2);

  diag(length(x)) - u %*% t(u) - v %*% t(v) + 
    cbind(u,v) %*% matrix(c(cost,-sint,sint,cost), 2) %*% t(cbind(u,v))
}


x=c(2,4,5,3,6)
y=c(6,2,0,1,7)

# Same norm  
sqrt(sum(x^2))
sqrt(sum(y^2))

Rx2y = rotation(x,y) 
x %*% Rx2y

#>      [,1] [,2]          [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    6    2 -8.881784e-16    1    7
```